# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{n}}$. Is my thinking correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to examine convergence of that sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{n}}$$

I think that it can be done like that:

$$ - \infty\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \infty$$

Sums on both hand sides converge to $0$.

However, I am nervous since I got $n \sqrt{2}$ under $cos$ and I not sure if my solution is correct (if I shouldn't find something more "advanced" / creative).

Comment: But $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ does *not* converge

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt n}= \infty$$

Comment: There is no absolute convergence so the result will depend on how you rearrange the infinite sum. You could have multiple results making the sum converge to whatever number you want.

Comment: @mymathc Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @mymathc Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The analysis is not correct.  First, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges.  So, the bounds in the OP are useless.

We can use Dirichlet's test.  Here we note the $\frac1{\sqrt n}$ monotonically decreases to $0$ and that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(n\sqrt 2)$ is uniformly bounded (i. e.  . there exists a number $M$ such that the absolute value of the sum is less than $M$ for all $N$).  The theorem gurantees that the series of interest converges.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I found many examples similar to this one. For instance: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cos(n+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n* ln(n^2 + 1)}$ could be done exactly the same way, am I right? I mean Dirichlet's test.

Comment: But how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos{(\sqrt 2n)}$ is bounded ?

Comment: @Saikai - there should be formula for this sum. One can derive one from the identity $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{ikx} = \frac{1-e^{i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}$$ and then taking real and imaginary parts and putting for x = $-i\sqrt 2$

Comment: Yeah, as I look at this right now I am not sure either. I mean, you could go to $\infty$ with that.

Comment: @mymathc Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @mymathc Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)