# How to prove that a sum: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n\sqrt 2)$ is uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove that a sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n\sqrt 2)$$
is uniformly bounded?

That problem is connected to an answer to other question that I have asked before:

[Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{cos(n \sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{n}}$. Is my thinking correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974494/convergence-of-sum-n-0-infty-fraccosn-sqrt2-sqrtn-is-my-thin?noredirect=1#comment8199544_3974494)

Comment: You mean to say that the partial sums of the series are uniformly bounded, not the series itself. Hint: if you write $\cos t = \frac12(e^{it}+e^{-it})$, the partial sums become geometric series.

Comment: Partial sums are bounded. 'Uniformly bounded' has no meaning here since there is no variable other than $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll provide two methods, one using complex numbers and one using sum-of-angle formulas. Let $b=\sqrt 2$.

---

Note that by Euler's formula:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N\cos\left(bn\right)&=\Re\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\cos\left(bn\right)+i\sin\left(bn\right)\right)\\
&=\Re\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ibn}\\
&=\Re\frac{e^{ib(N+1)}-e^{ib}}{e^{ib}-1}
\end{align*}

Here $e^{ib}-1\ne 0$ and $e^{ib(N+1)}$ is uniformly bounded, so the partial sum is also uniformly bounded.

---

To use trigonometry, you want to recall formulas for $f\left((n\pm 1)b\right)$ where $f$ is $\sin$ or $\cos$. In this case $\sin$ works:

\begin{align*}
\Delta_n&=\sin\left((n+1)b\right)-\sin\left((n-1)b\right)\\
&=\sin(nb)\cos(b)+\cos(nb)\sin(b)-\left\{\sin(nb)\cos(b)-\cos(nb)\sin(b)\right\}\\
&=2\cos(nb)\sin(b)
\end{align*}

Therefore we have a telescoping sum:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N\cos\left(bn\right)&=\frac{1}{2\sin\left(b\right)}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(\sin\left((n+1)b\right)-\sin\left((n-1)\right)b\right)\\
&=\frac{\sin\left((N+1)b\right)+\sin\left(Nb\right)-\sin\left(b\right)-\sin\left(0\right)}{2\sin(b)}
\end{align*}

Now again $\sin(b)\ne 0$ and $\sin((N+1)b)+\sin(Nb)$ is uniformly bounded, so the partial sum is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Looks good. I can only use the trigonometry so I appreciate especially that solution. I will look however for some easier starting formulas - do you think that it is possible to do it?

Comment: @mymathc That is beyond my knowledge. However I can do slightly better at incentivising the starting formula: It mimics the [central finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Basic_types), which is analogous to taking the derivative. Thus as $\sin$ *differentiates* to $\cos$, there is reason to believe that the finite difference also involves $\cos$ in a similar form.

Comment: @mymathc In a sense, you can think about summing $\cos(bn)$ as a Riemann sum for $\int \cos(x)$ where "$dx=b$", but there are more work to be done in order to formalize the intuition.

Comment: And could you tell me how did you get 1st line in the complex numbers? I get that from 1st to 2nd it's Euler's formula. It looks link you just add isin(bn) and I don't know how is it possible.

Comment: I used the real part ($\Re$) of it

Comment: Ohhh, I understand, than you